# Pass data array using data-id="" separated by ':' | PHP, HTML, SQL

Tags: php, html, json, ajax, sqlsrv

I currently have a dataTable in SQL, The data that I can manage to pass is only `$row['deptcode']`, Is there a way to pass more than 1 data-id into a modal and distribute it to separate input texts? If so, how will I pass it? and is there a way to pass the data into PHP as well?

Is it possible to do it like this? `data-id='".$row['deptcode'].":".$row['empno'].":".$row['departmentname'].":".$row['jobposition']."'`

```
 <div class="box-body">
              <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <th>Job ID</th>
                  <th>Latest Data</th>
                  <th>Department</th>
                  <th>Job Position</th>
                  <th>Payment Mode</th>
                  <th>Tools</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
$sql = "
SELECT DISTINCT 
LEFT (departmentcode,4) as deptcode,
MAX(RIGHT(employeeidno, 7)) as empno,
section,  departmentname, paymentmode,
hrdjobpositionentry.jobposition as jobposition
FROM departmentmasterfile, hrdjobpositionentry,employeemasterfile 
WHERE hrdjobpositionentry.department=departmentmasterfile.departmentname AND
LEFT (employeemasterfile.employeeidno,4) = LEFT (departmentmasterfile.departmentcode,4)
GROUP BY LEFT (departmentcode,4), section, departmentname, paymentmode, hrdjobpositionentry.jobposition
ORDER BY LEFT (departmentcode,4)";
                    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
                    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                      echo "
                        <tr>
                          <td>".$row['deptcode']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['empno']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['departmentname']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['jobposition']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['paymentmode']."</td>
                          <td><button class='btn btn-success btn-sm select btn-flat' data-id='".$row['deptcode']."'><i class='fa fa-select'></i> Select</button></td>
                        </tr>
                      ";
                    }
                  ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

Currently I can only pass this data to a single modal. Whenever I select row in the table, it can be passed through here.

```
<script>
$(function(){

    $("body").on('click', '.select', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#select').modal('show');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    getRow(id);
  });
});
```

Comment: you can use multiple `data` attribute like `data-deptcode` , `data-empno` ..

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, and then I'll change this ````var id = $(this).data('id');```` to ````var deptcode = $(this).data('deptcode');````, and so on, and add ````getRow(id);```` to ````getRow(deptcode);````, correct?

Comment: Why not just have a POJO and access it via the ID? Why pollute the DOM? You can even have JS create the table then from a simple JSON transfer

Comment: @mplungjan, I'm sorry, I'm completely new to this type of flow, could you please give me an example to study?

Comment: You tagged Ajax so I assume you can get the data from the backend so instead of creating the table in PHP, use json_encode to pass a `{ "aaa" : { "empno": 1, "departmentname": "a"......}, "bbb": {.......}}` where aaa and bbb are deptcodes. 
Then you can iterate over the deptcodes with JavaScript and generate the table with each row having a data-deptcode. Then the modal can easily access your POJO to get at the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**- On click of button, get all data of selected row using closest() method . https://api.jquery.com/closest/.

**Step 2**- using map, store all that required data in an array.

**Step 3** - use this array as parameter within getRow function.

**Step 4**- in getRow function using loop get the data of array and display in model

**jQuery code.**

```
<script>

function getRow(data){
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
              // console.log(index+':'+value);
    });

    //Get value by individual key
    var Job_ID = data['Job ID'];
    var Latest_Data = data['Latest Data'];
    var Department = data['Department'];
    var Job_Position = data['Job Position'];
    var Payment_Mode = data['Payment Mode'];

    console.log(Job_ID+':'+Latest_Data+':'+Department+':'+Job_Position+':'+Payment_Mode);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").on('click', '.select', function (e){
row = {};
e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').not(':last').map(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        var key = $('thead th').eq(index).text();
        value = $(this).text().trim();
        row[key] = value;
        });

    //you will get all the row data in array with key.
    console.log(row);

    getRow(row);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: My button will stay as it is? ````<td><button class='btn btn-success btn-sm select btn-flat' data-id='".$row['deptcode']."'><i class='fa fa-select'></i> Select</button></td>````

Comment: Yes, you can remove the data-id attr. That is not required. Because all the row data will get in array.

Comment: How will the other page capture this? like for example the **select** modal? Like for ````<td>".$row['deptcode']."</td>````, how will it be sent to the **select** modal? I apologize as this is confusing for me.

Comment: In my ans. I'm using getRow(row); in row you will get all the details like deptcode, empno etc in array. How you are using getRow function.

Comment: After click on button, check in console you will see all the required row data in array

Comment: I got this in the bottom part of my query ````function getRow(id){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'employee_data_row.php',
    data: {id:id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
$('.decid').val(response.employeeidno);````

Comment: im getting this data in console.. **0000016: "0000016"
D001: "D001"
DAILY: "DAILY"
SENIOR CASHIER STAFF: "SENIOR CASHIER STAFF"
TREASURY: "TREASURY"**

Comment: I'm not sure how will I turn that into output. will I use the same flow as ````$('.decid').val(response.employeeidno);````?

Comment: How will I output it in html? **0000016: "0000016" D001: "D001" DAILY: "DAILY" SENIOR CASHIER STAFF: "SENIOR CASHIER STAFF" TREASURY: "TREASURY"** Apologies on this matter. I got confused on posting the selected data row and display it in input texts.

Comment: I'm confused on how to achieve *Step 4- in getRow function using loop get the data of array and display in model*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197376/discussion-between-shivendra-singh-and-pjustindaryll).